Why is Abp. Viganò's (supposed) excommunication for schism "latæ sententiæ" (not "ferendæ sententiæ")?
Why is Abp. Viganò's (supposed) excommunication for schism latæ sententiæ (automatic), not ferendæ sententiæ (declared juridical sentence)?

What is the question? It is well known and easy to google, that penality for schism is excommunication latae sententiae. Why should there be a doubt in this case?

@K-HB "What is the question?" Why is it latae sententiae and not ferendæ sententiæ?

I don't understand the downvotes.  +1 trying to neutralize.

The Dicastry for the Doctrine of the Faith (DDF) said in its press release:

Press Release About the Conclusion of the Extrajudicial Penal ProcessAgainst His Excellency, the Most Rev. Carlo Maria Viganò (5 July 2024)
On 4 July 2024, the Congress of the Dicastery for the Doctrine of the
Faith met to conclude the extrajudicial penal process referred to in
canon 1720 CIC against the Most Reverend Carlo Maria Viganò, titular
Archbishop of Ulpiana, accused of the reserved delict of schism
(canons 751 and 1364 CIC; art. 2 SST [Sacramentorum sanctitatis tutela]).
His public statements manifesting his refusal to recognize and submit
to the Supreme Pontiff, his rejection of communion with the members of
the Church subject to him, and of the legitimacy and magisterial
authority of the Second Vatican Ecumenical Council are well known.
At the conclusion of the penal process, the Most Reverend Carlo Maria
Viganò was found guilty of the reserved delict of schism.
The Dicastery declared the latae sententiae excommunication in
accordance with canon 1364 § 1 CIC.
The lifting of the censure in these cases is reserved to the Apostolic
See.
This decision was communicated to the Most Reverend Viganò on 5 July
2024.

1983 Code of Canon Law

Can. 751 Heresy is the obstinate denial or obstinate doubt after the reception of baptism of some truth which is to be believed by divine and Catholic faith; apostasy is the total repudiation of the Christian faith; schism is the refusal of submission to the Supreme Pontiff or of communion with the members of the Church subject to him.


Can. 1364— § 1. An apostate from the faith, a heretic or a schismatic incurs a latae sententiae excommunication, without prejudice to the provision of can. 194 § 1 n. 2; he or she may also be punished with the penalties mentioned in can. 1336 §§ 2-4.

However, there is doubt he really is a heretic or in schism.
Viganò defends himself in his 28 June 2024 open letter:

Before my Brothers in the Episcopate and the entire ecclesial body, I accuse Jorge Mario Bergoglio of heresy and schism, and I ask that he be judged as a heretic and schismatic and removed from the Throne which he has unworthily occupied for over eleven years. This in no way contradicts the adage Prima Sedes a nemine judicatur*, because it is evident that, since a heretic is unable to assume the Papacy, he is not above the Prelates who judge him.

*"The First See is judged by no one"—i.e., the pope is the supreme judge
Viganò rejects

the errors and deviations implied by the so-called Second Vatican Ecumenical Council, which I consider to be completely devoid of magisterial authority due to its heterogeneity compared to all the true Councils of the Church, which I fully recognize and accept, just as I fully recognize and accept all the magisterial acts of the Roman Pontiffs.

cf. "For Catholics who have expressed concern about Pope Francis and are wary of his pontificate, what are the key issues?"

This answer doesn't really address why it is not  "ferendae sententiae" even though per Wikipedia " A ferendae sententiae penalty is a penalty that is inflicted on a guilty party only after a case has been brought and decided by an authority in the Church." which seems to be the case here.

@GratefulDisciple If it's latæ sententiæ, why did the DDF have to declare it? Wouldn't that make it ferendæ sententiæ?

And what's an "Extrajudicial Penal Process"?

So DDF used the wrong term?  If so, wouldn't it be helpful to make the answer more explicit?

It is not unknown for Rome to pronounce on latae sententiae when the person involved is extremely well known or has a many followers.

@GratefulDisciple I'm not claiming it did.

Vigano rejects the authority of the Second Vatican Council explicitly in the very quote you give for his "defense." This is at least schism, and if he rejects anything from Vatican 2 that is dogma (to be believed of Divine and Catholic Faith), that is, if there is any dogma at all (there are certainly dogmatic constitutions), then he is also plainly guilty of the crime of heresy. Moreover, he has elsewhere rejected Francis' pontificate, which of itself constitutes schism, as well.

As for your question why the DDF must declare it, the Holy See must declare any latae sententiae excommunication after having examined the case in order for us to know definitively that there was really a latae sententiae excommunication. The cause of his excommunication is his schismatic act itself, not the declaration by the DDF. The DDF merely has stated that, yes, in fact, Vigano has excommunicated himself by a schismatic act.
